# Writing to directory with 777 permission

Tags: ubuntu, ftp, directory, webserver, penetration-testing

It is usually said that if a directory has **777** permission , the world can write to it hence it is not supported.

Suppose I have domain like `abc.com/DIR`

**DIR** is the directory and has **777** permission, how anyonce can write to that directory without FTP Access ?

Comment: use a file upload program and upload your script there. Run it, hack it.

Comment: @urfusion you just cant do that without FTP creds, Filezilla, winscp all needs ftp creds

Comment: @urfusion any example software ?

Comment: Write a program on another server provide path for file uploading of that directory. That's it

Comment: @urfusion If I write a script then on receiving side I need to fetch that file as well using $_FILES etc. First you said **use** a file upload program and now saying to **write** a program . thanks anyways :)

Comment: What is said is  "use a file upload program and upload your script there". It mean write a program. When you write a program for file uploading then it takes files from your local system , it doesn't require the file to be on the server. Have you ever write a file uploading program?

Comment: @urfusion I did a lot, and it works in a way that when you upload a program on receiving side you need receive it as well.

Comment: provide me your domain and folder name which has `777`. I will do a hacking attempt.

Comment: @urfusion well cant really provide that due to privacy thats why I just asked for script or program

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The major problem with adding write access  for *others* is that any process running on the same machine can write into this directory.

By default apache, nginx, ... do not allow to upload files to a server and lets assume your server is configured that way, then you might think a write right for *others* might not be a problem, but that's not true.

Lets asume you have an application that itself does not execute or evaluate any scripts but somehow writes files based on some external input, then someone might find a way to control what this application writes on to the hard disk. This won't be a problem if the app will run with its own user and cannot write anywhere.

But now there is a folder with write rights for *others*  so this app could write there, e.g. placing a *php*  file in this directory. After the file is place there it can be evaluated/executed using *apache*.

A rule of thumb is always to run process with the least right they need, and the same is for the rights of the directories. If a web server only should reads the files then set owner of those files to a different user then the web-server, and only make them readable using the group rights.

Answer (score -1):

First take a look what `777` permission is:

**777 Permission**

The first digit is assigned to the Owner, the second digit is assigned to the Group and the third digit is assigned to the Others. So for a file with `777` permission, everyone can read, write and execute.

*Now come to your question*

If you provided `777` permission to the folder that mean everyone can read, write and execute. So it is easy to someone to create a file uploading program and upload a script (if it is not secure by htaccess) and execute it by simple URL.

For example

I wrote a program and upload a `php` file which use for empty directory or add some script which use for sending `spam` email then your server will be blacklisted.

File calling should be like `example.com/dir/myfile.php`

[There](https://askubuntu.com/questions/20105/why-shouldnt-var-www-have-chmod-777) is a good example why shouldn't use `777` permission.

Comment: @urlfusion, you answer doesn't tell about the question at all, i know what 777 is and how file upload works, I was just asking for the way to probably exploit 777.

Comment: if you are still not able to understand then I am not a spoon feeder.

Comment: @urlfusion let me send you the website url

Comment: the `x`flag for a directory does not mean every on can execute. The `x` flag on a directory does allows you to access files within the directory. By default no web-server allows to put files on there server. And if you configure to allow anonymous file uploads then this will happen with the right of the web server, so even if you don't grant rights for _others_  the file can be uploaded as long as it is writable for the user/group of the webserver. So removing the write access form other does not increase security in this situation.

Comment: @t.niese that helps, so by default it is blocked by apache or any webserver even my permissions are 777 , no one can write to it

Comment: @t.niese : have you read http://askubuntu.com/questions/20105/why-shouldnt-var-www-have-chmod-777?

Comment: @urfusion we normally heard that 777 is exploitable but never practically possibly may be due to default server permissions etc
As you can see on the link I gave you the permissions are 777

Comment: I looked at this link, but it does not say anything different, like I did. It is generally a bad idea that a file that is evaluated/executed or a directory contain those files is writable for a process that can manipulate files. In a secure _php_ setup the _php_  script are not writable by the _webserver_ or _php_fpm_ and you only execute scripts from a directory where _php_fpm_ and the _webserver_ cant write to. Write rights for others is the worst setting but removing this rights is just a small step to make the setup save.

Comment: @t.niese:  Yes, But this link and several other link simply saying that if a website has any upload functionality (user can upload files) then it is every easy to  someone to put a php file and run it. And one more thing in my answer I already describe that you allowed files by your htaccess. Normally this is the approach used by hacker.

Comment: To upload files with native apache or nginx functionality, then `PUT` needs to be enable, but this isn't true by default.
If you have any other upload functionality (WebDAV, php, ...) then even setting the rights to `0700` does not help much if the user of the directory/file is the same as the _webserver_ or the _php_fpm_  process, because this user can still write. And enabling anonymous ftp in such an insecure way is even bigger fault then using `0777`. Again, I agree that write for _others_  is bad, but to think `0744` or `0755` makes a server save is a false assumption.